# Is there any way to iterate through Orange table in python script?

Tags: python, data-mining, orange

Below is the code to import images into Orange and the list of imported images is stored in Orange table:

```
import Orange
from orangecontrib.imageanalytics.import_images import ImportImages
import_images = ImportImages()
data, err = import_images("E:/CME/CME3/Project Work/domestic-animals")    
if data:
    print(data)
    print(err)
    print(type(data))
```

imported images are stored in data variable as a table.

Output:

```
>>> 
Running script:
[[] {calf, calf.png, 45538, 191, 152},
 [] {cat, cat.png, 22193, 105, 137},
 [] {chick, chick.png, 14891, 85, 92},
 [] {cow, cow.png, 62159, 210, 189},
 [] {crow, crow.jpg, 6778, 259, 194},
 [] {dog, dog.png, 28745, 129, 125},
 [] {duck, duck.png, 39583, 158, 172},
 [] {duckling, duckling.png, 17109, 99, 119},
 [] {foal, foal.png, 39210, 147, 177},
 [] {goat, goat.png, 53039, 221, 179},
 [] {goose, goose.png, 34442, 141, 202},
 [] {hen, hen.png, 41716, 134, 168},
 [] {horse, horse.png, 69109, 285, 195},
 [] {kid, kid.png, 36290, 170, 160},
 [] {lamb, lamb.png, 35520, 123, 168},
 [] {Milka, Milka.jpg, 111090, 533, 800},
 [] {ox, ox.png, 56401, 191, 189},
 [] {rabbit, rabbit.png, 24294, 97, 174},
 [] {rooster, rooster.png, 41518, 145, 180},
 [] {sheep, sheep.png, 58022, 214, 181},
 [] {turkey, turkey.png, 55072, 171, 182}]
0
<class 'Orange.data.table.Table'>
>>>
```

The data variable is of type Table.
I want to access the column of .png files. How can I iterate through the above table?
I tried to iterate using for loop:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    files = data[i][1]
```

But I got this error:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried going through the relevant parts of the [tutorial](https://orange-data-mining-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/data.html#data-instances) or the [API reference](https://orange-data-mining-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/data.instance.html)?

Comment: Yes I went through tutorial. Well I found the way to do it. It is working now

Comment: Welcome to answer your own question then. 

Answer (score 0):

Of every RowInstance (data[i]), you can get these items ({...}) by calling them with **metas**.

See: https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-data-mining-library/en/latest/reference/data.instance.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30572298)

Comment: Ivan is right.
The other options is to simply iterate through metas:
`for i in data.metas:`